# Matrix with respect to Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

In part iii) It doesn't give a particularly wholesome answer and I don't really see where to start with this

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the first column of the matrix $A$ we calculate:

$$M\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)=\color{red}1\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)+\color{red}1\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
hence the first column is $(1,1,0,0)^T$. Do the same thing for the other columns.

Comment: Thanks, I've applied the method and got the desired matrix, i'm just wondering why this is equal to the matrix A.

Comment: I don't understand. What matrix?

Comment: It says in the solution that A= the matrix I calculated via your method (which has determinant 36). I know this matrix is T wrt the basis, but I do not understand why this is also equal to A.